# Trouble with differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm stuck on this differentiation question and its driving me insane. Can someone help showing all the steps?

Differentiate $(x+2)\left[(x-3)^2 +4\right]$

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you know about the product rule for differentiation?

Comment: At this stage you can expand out brackets and determine with the first rules of differentiating powers of $x$. If you were meant to use the product rule then go and look at that bit. If thats exhausted then write out what you have done here (don't worry about formatting for the first posts).

Comment: Take help of product rule $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$ here $u=(x+2)$ and $v=(x^2-6x+13)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\{ (x+2)((x-3)^2 +4)\}=((x-3)^2 +4)\cdot (x+2)' \quad+ (x+2)\cdot ((x-3)^2 +4)'=
((x-3)^2 +4)\cdot 1+(x+2) (2(x-3)\cdot1 +0)=
(3x+1) (x-3)+4
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x+2)[(x-3)^2+4]$$
$$=[(x-3)^2+4]\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x+2)+(x+2)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}[(x-3)^2+4]$$
$$=[(x-3)^2+4]\cdot (1+0)+(x+2) \cdot [2(x-3)\cdot 1]$$
$$=(x-3)^2+4+2(x+2)(x-3)$$

Rest you can simplify.

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems, just do it slowly for the time being. You want the derivative of $$y=(x+2)\left((x-3)^2 +4\right)$$ which is a product. So, define $u=(x+2)$ and $v=(x-3)^2 +4$. So $$y=u\times v \implies y'=u'\times v+u\times v'$$ For $u$, it is simple ($u'=1$). For $v$, you could do the same since we do not care about the $4$. Since $v=w^2+4$, the power law gives $v'=2\times w\times w'$. Since $w=x-3$, then $w'=1$.

Combine all the above.

I am sure that you can it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Product rule: "first times derivative of second plus second times derivative of first"

I still hear it in my head in Mr Broughall's voice.

Your first term is: $x+2$
Your second term is: $(x-3)^2+4$

To work out the derivative of $(x-3)^2$ use the chain rule, which is "derivative of the bracket times the derivative of what's inside the bracket"

Comment: (This is deliberately not a full answer because of doing homework on this site)